# Why does Pale Moon open URLs in the main profile when I clearly tell it to use a specific profile?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, palemoon

I've had massive problems with profiles in both Firefox (which I used to use) and Pale Moon for all the years I've used them. They seem to be fundamentally broken somehow, with numerous weird glitches and quirks. However, I can't even get Pale Moon to open any URL in a specific profile. It just uses the default profile, entirely ignoring the specified profile.

Example command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Pale Moon\palemoon.exe" -P "test profile" "https://www.example.com/"
```

That opens the URL in the default profile -- not in the profile called "test profile". (And yes, it does exist.)

Since Pale Moon doesn't even have its command line arguments documented, instead referring to Firefox's documentation, it must be the same switch (-P), yet it's just ignored...

Comment: check [Pale Moon's source code](https://github.com/MoonchildProductions/UXP/blob/a219152bddead6b34f40ae86217f39fbda91aab6/ipc/chromium/src/base/command_line.cc)